# accessing values from an array of objects nested within another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that returns the amount of times a specific account id has created a "borrow" record.
the code I currently have looks like this,

```
function numberOfBorrows(account, books) {
  let borrows = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < account.length; i++){
    let accountID = account[i].id;
    for (let j = 0; j < books.length; j++){
      let bookID = books[j].borrows;
      for (let h = 0; h < bookID.length; i++){
        let usersID = bookID[h].id;
        if (accountID === usersID) {
          borrows += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return borrows;
}
```

the data is coming from here,

```
const accounts = [
  {
    id: "5f446f2ecfaf0310387c9603",
    picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
    age: 25,
    name: {
      first: "Esther",
      last: "Tucker",
    },
    company: "ZILLACON",
    email: "esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
    registered: "Thursday, May 28, 2015 2:51 PM",
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed46724f41c9fc431",
    picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
    age: 35,
    name: {
      first: "Ferrell",
      last: "Morris",
    },
    company: "ECOLIGHT",
    email: "ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
    registered: "Thursday, February 8, 2018 1:16 PM",
  },
```

```
const books = [
  {
    id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
    title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8,
    borrows: [
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      }}]
```

Im completely unsure on how to solve this problem and loop through all the different nested array and for some reason the borrows variable keeps coming back as 0.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an array `reduce` method to aggregate counts of borrows in an object, keyed by the borrower's ID. This object can be used in the future whenever you need the number of borrows for any person.

```js
const books = [
  {
    id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
    title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8,
    borrows: [
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      }
    ]
  }
]

const borrows = books.reduce((acc, el) => {
  el.borrows.forEach(borrow => {
    acc[borrow.id] = (acc[borrow.id] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(borrows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using reduce and filter,

```js
const accounts = [
  {
id: "5f446f2ecfaf0310387c9603",
picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
age: 25,
name: {
  first: "Esther",
  last: "Tucker",
},
company: "ZILLACON",
email: "esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
registered: "Thursday, May 28, 2015 2:51 PM",
  },
  {
id: "5f446f2ed46724f41c9fc431",
picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
age: 35,
name: {
  first: "Ferrell",
  last: "Morris",
},
company: "ECOLIGHT",
email: "ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
registered: "Thursday, February 8, 2018 1:16 PM",
  }];


const books = [
  {
    id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
    title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
    genre: "Science",
    authorId: 8,
    borrows: [
      {
        id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
        returned: false,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
        returned: true,
      }
    ]
  }
]

const numberOfBorrows = (account, books) => {
  const borrows = books.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 return acc + curr.borrows.filter(item => item.id === account).length;
  }, 0);
  return borrows;
}

const ret = accounts.map(item => {
 return {id: item.id, borrowCount: numberOfBorrows(item.id, books)};
});

console.log(ret);
```